# How to check if the JSON data is one object or an array of objects?

Tags: json, javascript

I got server responsed JSON data:

```
var data = SERVER_RESPONSE;
```

this `data` could be an object `{id: 12, name: John}`,

it could also be an array of objects `[{id: 12, name: John}, {id: 22, name: OMG}]`

In Javascript, how can I check if the JSON `data` is one object or an array of objects?

Answer (score 14):

You could use the following test:

```
if (data instanceof Array) {
    // data is an array
} else {
    // it is not an array
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple test is to check for the existence of `obj.length` and `obj[0]`.

It's not 100% fool proof, but if you know that your data can only appear in one of the two formats you put in the question it should be sufficient.